# Why aren't my products being listed?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have **26,313** products on my magento website thats according to my categories page

[image]

but for some reason it shows me having **4126** products on the manage products page

[image]

I have all together **407** configurable products and the rest are simple products, but for some reason only 184 configurable products are shown on the front, and i've checked the stock levels, status, category, etc can magento handle this many products ?

Comment: do you have any filters applied?

Comment: No I don't have any filters applied.

Comment: Did you select the correct store/store view/website?

Comment: Yeh I updated the attributes so every product is on the correct store.

Comment: Magento can handle that many products, you are not running into any limits like that. 

Can you clarify what you mean by "categories page". That tiny crop of a screenshot doesn't look like the Admin categories page and I cannot tell where on the site you're seeing 26313 products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted I had to erase all my products because after looking into my magento backend I saw that I had 22000 simple products which had the status as disabled but for some reason I couldn't get to them using search as they wouldn't show, so after changing all the status to enabled on the database that still didn't make them show up, so I had to erase all the simple products and redo them all through the configurable product taking forever but that's the only solution that seemed to work for me.